# grep: Invalid back reference for date expression in tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tcsh, rhel-5

I googled for the following error, and didn't get any great explanations as to what was going on with grep under tcsh.  (Yes, that date expression exists in the log files).

```
$ grep '2014-07-21' *.log
grep: Invalid back reference
```

Curiously, if I switch to bash, the command works fine (that is my current work-around).  Anyone know what's going on here?

Because someone will ask, here are the results of `which` and `alias`:

```
$ which grep
/bin/grep

$ alias grep
$               # (Nothing)
```

This is running on RHEL 5.4 (Red Hat).

Comment: It looks as if **tcsh** expands single-quoted text into unquoted text with a back-slash before each character, in your case **\2\0\1\4\-\0\7\-\2\1**. **grep** interprets \{digit} as the offending back reference. The command should be OK without the quotes, which are unnecessary for your search strong. **bash** gives the same error if you use both the quotes and the back-slashes. Note that I have inferred this conclusion, but I don't have **tcsh** loaded to confirm it.

Comment: Indeed, taking off the quotes works!  Interesting.  However, if my grep was something more complicated like: `grep -P "2014-07-\d*"`, then tcsh forces me back to using quotes, and it works again.  Very curious.

Comment: I can only guess how **tcsh** might handle double-quotes, but your original search might well work with them.

Comment: @AFH - Finally found it!  It's a RedHat 5.4 bug that has to do with buggy glob matching (i.e.: '*.log').

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=529703) in Tcsh in the particular version of Tcsh and RedHat that I am using.  Apparently there is a patched version of tcsh available for this issue, as [described in this errata](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2010-0190.html), for RedHat 5.4:

```
Expansion of multiple filename globs failed if any glob in a command line
expression failed. The correct behavior outlines that a glob command should
only fail if all components of the command fail. This behavior is restored
with this updated package. (BZ#529703)
```

I checked, and I do indeed have the buggy version of tcsh installed as noted in the bug report above:

```
$ rpm -qa tcsh
tcsh-6.14-14.el5_4.2
```

Evidently the IT department for my company has not installed this tcsh patch yet (though I recently learned we'll soon be finally upgrading to RedHat EL 6.x).